# In jjtree, is there a way to traverse the generated parse tree and track changes to the value

Tags: javacc

I'm new to JJTree parsing. I've gone through basics. In jjtree, is there a way to traverse the generated parse tree and track changes to the value?

Say for example I've a JJTree which produces the following tree structure:

```
<parent name="xx">
 <child age="21" family="true">
 </child>
<parent>
<parent name="xy">
 <child age="21" family="true">
 </child>
<parent>
```

Here, i'd like to change the family as "false" for parent having name "xy". I'm struggling in this part.

My code needs a similar change. As my code increases complexity to understand, I've given here a sample which is understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To traverse the tree, you can use a visitor object.  See [the documentation](https://javacc.java.net/doc/JJTree.html).